# How to specify my 'environment' in ESLint?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

I'm currently using [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) in my project, and have configured it to run inside VSCode, and enforce a custom ruleset.  So far it is working as expected, and flagging lines in my code where violations occur.  I now need to specify that the `environment` is `browser` (as suggested in the solution to [this issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4015)).  How exactly do I do that, yet keep everything else about ESLint working as-is?

- That GitHub issue indicates I need to edit my `.eslintrc` file.  But I don't see any such file in the root of my project.  I *do* see `.eslint` files in several different dependencies, e.g.

`C:\Users\snarl\development-snarl\development-wordpress\linting-wordpress\node_modules\is-callable`

I could be wrong, but those don't seem related.

- I tried creating a new file--`.eslintrc.json`--in the root of my project, and adding to that file:

`{
    "env": {
      "browser": true
    }
 }`

But when I did this, and re-checked ESLint inside VSCode, it stopped flagging the rules in my custom ruleset ([examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uazo.jpg)), and actually flagged a new rule ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vkxv.jpg)).  This seems to completely supersede some of my existing ESLint settings, rather than supplement them.

Thanks.

Comment: The file must be named `.eslintrc`. Not `.eslintrc.json`. Rename the file, remove the `.json` extension.

Comment: The suffix is fine, see the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring). I use the 'json' suffix for my config. @cag8f Where did you set your custom rules, if not in a config file?

Comment: @hotpink The custom rules are in a separate Node package (this one:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/eslint-plugin/v/1.0.0), which is installed as a dependency in my project.  So from the root directory of my project, that package is located in `node_modules/@wordpress`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posed this question to the ESLint Google Group ([see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/eslint/pnhSCNyzxGg)), and received a reply with the answer.  If there is no ESLint config file in my project's root directory, ESLint falls back and looks for one in the user's root directory.  I checked that directory on my computer, and there was indeed an ESLint config file there (.eslint.json).  If I create a new config file in my project's root directory, that will supersede the config file in the user root directory.  So the solution was to move the config file from my user root directory to my project's root directory, then to it, add the env lines:

```
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
}
```

That resolved my issue.  After, ESLint inside VSCode continued to lint my files, using the same custom rule set.  Furthermore, ESLint seemed to understand that the `env` was `browser.`  Although I didn't explicitly check that.  I say that because the ESLint error that was previously reported, was no longer reported.  And my assumption is that is occurring because the `env` has been properly set to `browser` (as per [this issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4015)).